# influxdb delete query with time AND non-time clause

Tags: influxdb

Per documentation, deleting is supported only if where clause has time. That works fine. But, if I want to narrow down by time and another clause, it errors out..is that supported yet?
ie. delete from datapoints where time>now()-1h and code='12345'

Answer (score 0):

The relevant documentation: http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/query_language.html#deleting-data-or-dropping-series

The `DELETE` syntax for individual points is only valid in 0.8 and prior versions. All development is on the 0.9 version and no work is being done to fix any 0.8 issues. Therefore the current functionality of `DELETE FROM` is final for all 0.8.x versions.

Comment: so, the answer is "no"..?

Comment: I haven't tested it to verify, so I cannot say for certain the answer is "no", but whatever the behavior is now will not change.